# Product of Ideals

Tags: abstract-algebra, ideals

Can I define the product of ideals $I, J$ as $$IJ = \left\{\sum_{j}^n \sum_{i}^n a_i b_j| a_i \in I, b_j \in J, i,j \in \mathbb{N}\right\}.$$ Are there some books that define the product of ideals like this? My professor asked me the explanation of product of ideal $$AB=\left\{\sum_{i}^n a_i b_i| a_i \in A, b_i \in B, n \in \mathbb{N}\right\}.$$ And she asked me if this definition means that the number of elements in $A$ are equal to $B$. So, what if the number of elements is different? Could someone explain this? Thanks.

Comment: If the setting is commutative then yes you can define the product of ideals that way. Two ideals don't necessarily have the same number of elements (what does that have to do with products of ideals anyway)? "What if the number of elements is different?" is quite broad of a question. It's like asking "what if two numbers are different?" Well ... then they're different.

Answer (score 2):

A general element in the product of two ideals $\,I\,,\,J\,$ is a finite sum of elements of the form $\,xy\;,\;\;x\in I\;,\;y\in J\;$...which is exactly what you wrote in your second definition (understanding $\,n\in\Bbb N\,$ is variable, not fixed.

Elements of the form $\,x\;,y\;,\;x+y\;$ etc. , do not usually belong to the product. One way of getting convinced of this is to realize that $\,IJ\subset I\cap J\;$ , so if we had, for example, for$\;x\in I\;;\;\; x\in IJ\,$ ,  then

$$x\in IJ\subset I\cap J\le J$$

which of course doesn't generally holds.

So yes: the finite sums of products of elements, one in the first ideal and the other in the second one, means that the number of elements taking part in each such a product in each particular element of $\,IJ\,$ is the same.