# Are there any ordering for the elements of an ideal?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals

In page 17 of "Introduction to Grobner basis" by R. Froberg, the multiplication of two ideals is defined as follows:

> $ \mathcal{a} \cdot \mathcal{b} = \left\{ \sum_{i=1}^{k} a_i \cdot b_i \vert a_i \in \mathcal{a}, b_i \in \mathcal{b} \right\} $

There is no problem understanding this. But I cannot get the point here. Ideals are subsets of a ring with two properties, closed w.r.t. to sum of two elements and closed w.r.t. left multiplication by elements of the underlying ring. They are **sets** and as I know, sets in general does not have any orders on them unless specified separately.

What does it mean to multiply $a_i \cdot b_i$ (the multiplication is clear, but the indexes are not! We do not have any order on the ideals as far as I know)? Moreover, does it mean that $k \leq \min \left\{ \vert \mathcal{a} \vert , \vert \mathcal{b} \vert \right\}$?

There are similar questions to this, the one ([Product of Ideals](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/431447/product-of-ideals)) but does not provide any answers related to my question. Plus, I am new to abstract algebra and studying this book on myself.

Comment: $a_i$ and $b_i$ are elements of the ideals $a$ resp. $b$. You know what multiplying ring elements means. The product of the two ideals is defined as the set of finite sums of ring elements of the form $\alpha\cdot\beta$, where $\alpha\in a,\; \beta\in b$.

Comment: @DanielFischer Thanks for your response. Does your comment mean that the indexes of $a_i$ and $b_i$ are irrelevant here and they just want to denote some elements of those ideals?

Comment: The indices just serve to count, so that we have a finite sum. They have no deeper meaning.

Comment: Thanks @DanielFischer. Moreover, I have edited the question to make clarifications.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the discussions in comments under the question, I found the point:

> The indexes just serve to count, so that there is a *finite* sum. They have no deeper meaning.

This way, my second question is also solved, about the maximum value of $k$. It is not bounded, but should be $k < \infty$.

Comment: Salam. Mamnoon. Man taze varedam inja va albate az ghavaed inja etela nadashtam. Az rooye profile shoma natoonestam motavajeh besham ke eftekhar ham sohbati ba kodom yeki az doostan ghadimi nasibam shode.

Comment: Mamnunam. Fek nakonam hamo beshnasim amma khob khosh halam ke inja yeki dg az khodemuno peyda kardam. Man ham ye 2 sali hast ke haraz chand gahi miyam inja soali chizi ro age balad basham shikase pikase jawab midam.